# Number of colourings of edges of a regular octahedron using n colours

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, geometry

I am playing around with polyhedra symmetry, and can find the number of colourings of faces of an octahedron with ease, when rotations are considered the same colouring. I am struggling to convert this to finding the polynomial in the number of colours when trying to colour the edges of a regular octahedron with different rotations counting to be the same colouring. I have been using the orbit counting formula for this, but cannot get a polynomial which gives integer results for a number of colours. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's the same as the number of edge colourings of the cube. Personally I'd rather work it out for the cube. I find cubes easier to visualize than octahedra, because I have more of them lying around the house.

Answer (score 5):

There are $24$ symmetries of the octahedron. With respect to edges, they break down as follows:

- $1$ identity; $n^{12}$ colourings are fixed by this symmetry
- $6$ quarter-turns around an octahedron vertex ($n^3$ each)
- $3$ half-turns around a vertex ($n^6$)
- $6$ half-turns around an edge ($n^7$)
- $8$ third-turns around a face ($n^4$)

So the number of colurings up to rotation is, by Burnside's lemma,
$$\frac{n^{12}+6n^7+3n^6+8n^4+6n^3}{24}$$
which gives $218$ colourings with $n=2$ and $22815$ with $n=3$. (This gives [OEIS A060530](https://oeis.org/A060530).)